# How do I determine the rotation of a Tile using Tilemap in Unity 2d?

Tags: unity, 2d, tilemap

I want to know the rotation of the tile in C# in order to do some logic on another object that is sitting on the tile. The rotation matters for the logic. I don't see anything except GetTileData [in the doc](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Tilemaps.TileBase.html), but that doesn't actually seem to "Get" the tile data. I could cast to Tile but not all tiles are Tile. Alternatively, I think I can get the rotation if I can get the GameObject for the tile but I have no idea how to do that either from a BaseTile.

Anyone have any suggestions? Maybe I'm trying to do this wrong and I should make different tiles for each orientation or extend BaseTile or some other solution instead of trying to determine rotation. Any help or ideas would be greatly appreciated!

Additional info: When I inspect around in the Unity editor I see that the rotation is stored in Z in something called "Grid Selection" but I can't find a programmatic way of accessing that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks to @Arkeus in the [Unity Developer Community Discord](https://discord.gg/BwU3uqw) for helping me out with this!

You need to get the transformation matrix of a specific tile in a tilemap. That includes the rotation information of the specific tile.

```
myTilemap.GetTransformMatrix(Vector3Int).rotation
```